# Videojs - Define how far into the future a video is "preloaded" or "fetched"

Tags: video.js

My question is hard to explain because I don't know the right video.js terminology but I'll try my best.

Have a look at this image:

[image: videojs timeline loading]

You see the white circle where the video is currently playing at, then a gray line after that indicating how much video has been downloaded or "pre-loaded" or "fetched".

All I want to know is, is there a setting in videojs that lets me control how far into the future the video "pre-loads" in advance?

**Why do I care?**

Right now, the video loads about 1 minute ahead. When I scrub the timeline or resize the browser from small to large, the video resolution quality is stuck on the lower resolution until about 1 minute has passed, then it automatically switches. I want to reduce this time from 1 minute to something like 10 seconds so it's only fetching about 10 seconds into the future.